# How to run a pytest fixture on a remote machine

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline, pytest, remote-server, fixtures

**setup:** I am using Jenkins (pipelines) + pytest for our automation framework. We have a jenkins master running on Ubuntu and it is connected to agents A (machine running Windows 10) and B (machine running Windows 10)

**Problem:** We have a functional test that needs to run on machine B. This test requires two fixtures to run first: fixtureA will need to run on machine A (to setup machine A), and fixtureB will need to run on machine B.
Is there a plugin/feature that will allow control over where each fixture will run? Specifically in the example above, I need fixtureA to run on machine A.

I know I can have fixtureA be defined as a normal function and specify in the jenkins pipeline to run that function on machine A. But that will defeat the whole purpose of using pytest (which is having pytest manage all setup and cleanup logic for the different tests).

Feel free to suggest changing the whole setup if needed (I am pretty flexible here).

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and so far logic way - having fixture builder what runs functions(convert fixtures A,B to functions) in case of condition:

```
@pytest.fixture
def env_builder():
    if condition:
        return run_function1()
    else
        return run_function2()
```